# How to exit apt-get?

Tags: apt, software-center

When I try to install new software from the Ubuntu Software Center, it says "waiting for apt-get to exit". How I can exit apt-get?

Answer (score 7):

It is more likely that you have another instance of `apt-get` running at the same time. The way to exit it is:

1. If `apt-get` was started by you, either wait for it to finish or if you are at the "Y/n" prompt, answer it.
2. If it's running in  the background, just **wait for it to finish**. Normally this happens when apt is updating or upgrading packages.

You can see what apt is doing by opening a terminal and typing `ps ax | grep apt`. This will tell you what `apt-get` is doing at the moment:

```
$ ps ax | grep apt
26890 pts/1    S+     0:00 sudo apt-get upgrade
26956 pts/4    S+     0:00 grep apt
```

Please **do not try to forcefully end apt**. It's more likely that you will end up with a crippled system if you do.