# How to fix the error 'waiting for apt-get to exit'?

Tags: apt, gnome, language-support

When I was installing another language in settings of Gnome on Ubuntu, system gave the message - 'Waiting for apt-get to exit'.

How can I fix the error, and install the language in GNOME settings?

Comment: Sorry I do not see the question this answer appears to belong to.

Comment: @Sherman; Title needs to be related to the Question, and an elaborated actual Question needs to be present, then you may `Answer your own question` and type that (the Answer) in the provided box. You have the Question in the Title only, and a terse answer in the question-field.

Comment: Oh. I see. Thank both of you for pointing it out. I will edit it then

Comment: @ShermanChen You can answer your own question, as you initially did.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Thank you! I will.

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi  Sorry, but I do not see the 'Your Answer' input box.

Comment: Your question was closed because it initially was not a question. It is getting reopen votes. Once it is reopened, you can add the answer

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi Oh, I see. Thank you!

Comment: @ShermanChen Reopened: go for it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the following, and it worked -

Find the pid of apt-get

```
$ sudo ps -el --sort cmd
```

e.g. the pid is 18374, then kill it

```
$ sudo kill 18374
```

Answer (score 0):

The following method was used to solve the problem.

Find the pid of the apt-get process:

```
ps -el --sort cmd
```

For example, if the pid is 18374, then kill it:

```
sudo kill 18374
```

The following method is safer than the first method.

Please do not try to forcefully end apt, because it may harm your system. If apt-get was started by you, either wait for it to finish or if you are at the "Y/n" prompt, answer it. If apt-get is running in the background, just wait for it to finish. <sup>[source](https://askubuntu.com/a/369203/)</sup>

Comment: The first part was my answer, but thank you for your answer anyhow!

Comment: Sorry, I waited for some time, but it did not die, so I killed it, and I was lucky. :)